# BEGIN {...}; in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

BEGIN {
        print "That's BEGIN message\n";
BEGIN { print "That's BEGIN-2 message\n"; };
END { print "That's END message\n"; };
BEGIN { print "That's BEGIN-3 message\n"; };
};
```

It works so:

```
That's BEGIN-2 message
That's BEGIN-3 message
That's BEGIN message
That's END message
```

But why? It must prints in line 1 `That's BEGIN message` or no?

Comment: I'm curious as how you came to think of writing this code?

Comment: @simlev I don't know))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `BEGIN` isn't run until it is **completely** defined (see [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)).  That doesn't happen until the end of the last **`}`**.

The others get run as they're completely defined — earlier.